# Simplify Hypergeometric function ${\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(-i,-i;\,1-2\,i,2-i;\,{{\rm e}^{Y}})}$

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Any suggestion how I could simplify this function, where $i$ is the complex unit?

$${\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(-i,-i;\,1-2\,i,2-i;\,{{\rm e}^{Y}})}$$

I allready tried, without success, to simplify this expression with Maple using

`simplify(...,hypergeom)`

Or is there at least a way to express this function approximately?

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: Silly question, but is $i$ the complex unit?

Comment: @kennytm: It is one solution to a 3rd order linear ODE with nonconstant coefficients. The general solution had more terms, but I selected the parameter to reduce to this form.

Comment: @ Bacon: $i$ is the complex unit.